# Can i send an @entity through TCP java socket?

Tags: java, hibernate, tcp, entity

all my test fails ... so is possible send an @entity using a TCP socket?

**UPDATE**

Problem is related at this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3097269/hibernate-send-entity-through-tcp-lose-persistentbagor-not-update-it

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you should be able to send any object that is [`Serializable`](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/Serializable.html) through a socket. The `@Entity` annotation has probably nothing to do with it.

Could you however refine your exact problem and what you are trying to do? As it is now, it doesn't make much sense.

Comment: However it might be more convenient to use RMI if allowed in your infrastructure.

Comment: Hi, my major prob is explained in this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3097269/hibernate-send-entity-through-tcp-lose-persistentbagor-not-update-it

Answer (score 0):

You can send everything that fits into an array of bytes.